# Boneshape's wireframe drawn the smaller the bone is

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, armature, bones

[image]

I'm using a bone with a complex mesh as it's boneshape, the smaller this bone is the more edges it draws on viewport. why does this happen? is it a graphical thing, or is it a way for blender to calculate small meshes?

Is there a way to prevent this?

[image]
Blend file was made using Blender 3.0

Comment: can u provide your blend file?

Comment: @Chris i have updated the post with a download to the .blend

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? I can't reproduce the effect on the GIF on 2.93.0: https://i.imgur.com/CKhkCFW.gif

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I'm using 3.0, apologies for not mentioning in the post

Answer (score 1):

You enabled it in the viewport overlay.
There you can set in Geometry wireframe a threshold value.
You should not worry about it, it doesn't render.

Comment: i don't think that's what my problem is, this is not the mesh, this is a bone with a boneshape. the geometry wireframe value doesn't affect bones

Comment: So the White hand is not a mesh??

Comment: no, the white hand is a boneshape that is using a duplicate of the hand as a mesh. that way it looks like i am selecting the hand but i am really just selecting the boneshape. its an aesthetic thing